# NetBeans - "no Axis2 url specified" when I click on test operation in browser

Tags: netbeans, apache-axis, weblogic-10.x

I'm writing a simple web service using Axis2 and NetBeans 8.0, my (very simple) code looks like this:

[image]

and my configuration of Axis2 in Tools panel (I'm using oracle weblogic 10.3.6) is this:

[image]

but when I click on "test operation in browser" I have this error:

[image: <axis2_err>]

even if it seems to be ok. What I'm doing wrong?